# get_time not operating as expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I was playing around with the **`put_time`** and **`get_time`** functions and I ran into some problems.

I took this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream ss("2011-Februar-18 23:12:34");
    ss.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf-8"));
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S");

    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
    }
}
```

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time). However, when compiling with both gcc version 8.8.1  and clang version 6.0.0 I get parse failed, even though the exacmple at cppreference should work with clang.

Anyone who could enlighten me what goes wrong?

Comment: FWIW, if you run the code on cppreference it also fails.

Comment: Select clang and it works.

Comment: Which C++ library are you using with clang?

Comment: in the link OP gave it is clearly said _Example
note: choose clang to observe the output. libstdc++ does not correctly implement the %b specifier: bug 78714_

Comment: @Tyker The answer box is below

Comment: clang++ -std=gnu++14 main.cpp  -o test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the link OP gave it is clearly said

> Example
>
> note: choose clang to observe the output. libstdc++ does not
> correctly implement the %b specifier: [bug 78714](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78714)

Comment: It still fails when using clang: clang++ -std=gnu++14 main.cpp -o test

Comment: probably clang using gcc library

Comment: Ow joy. How would I instruct clang to use it's own libraries, to verify?

Comment: you must have `stdc++`(clang's librairy) installed and then add a `-stdlib=libc++` to compliation